# Available Node Package Module that supports amazon product api version 5.0

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-product-api, paapi

Amazon recently published its Amazon Product Advertising API v5.0 for Amazon Affiliate Program. From 31st October 2019, previous version 4.0 of API will be taken down and only v5.0 will be supported to access Amazon products programmatically.

With these changes, most available node modules and applications will no longer work with V5.0. For this Amazon PA-API 5.0, Amazon has released an [SDK](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/with-sdk.html) for PHP, NodeJs, Python and, Java. However, using the SDK for NodeJs may require time to configure.

That being said, is there an available Node Package module that we can use to easily start integrating our application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few NPM wrappers that are available today that help you use Paapi 5.0 for NodeJS. All of this module uses the amazon [SDK](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/quick-start/using-sdk.html#nodejs) for their code.

1. [amazon-paapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-paapi) - By far my favorite as it uses simple to understand node syntax. Adding parameters is much like how you do it using amazon [scratchpad](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/scratchpad/index.html). It also support custom parameter options.
2. [amazon-pa-api50](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-pa-api50) - Another great module. However, as of this writing, I found some limitations on optional parameters you can add to some operations.
3. [apaw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@johnfoderaro/apaw) - alternative option.